# How to query all documents where array field have at least one object-element with property equal 'X'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I have some MongoDB documents like that:

```
{
"group": "P32666",
"order": [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e8e9b40e7999f6b90fd88bf"
    },
    "name": "Dmitriy A",
    "login": "example",
    "password": "example",
    "email": "example",
    "level": "user",
    "uuid": "b6a19744-bb20-4d39-9e1e-0ca5b464f890"
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e8ea03f5a21c26b90983de4"
    },
    "name": "Dmitriy B",
    "login": "example",
    "password": "example",
    "email": "example",
    "level": "user",
    "uuid": "556924c3-605c-44cc-8a26-d32f58222e89"
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e8ea0645a21c26b90983de5"
    },
    "name": "Dmitriy C",
    "login": "example",
    "password": "example",
    "email": "example",
    "level": "user",
    "uuid": "aef00707-ef00-4ce9-918b-5cef17e7280b"
}]}
```

I'm working with Mongo in Mongoose and can't understand how to query all documents(like above) where field(array) "order" has at least one object within where field, for example, "login" is queal to "example". How can I do this?

I tried something like this:

```
export async function getQueues(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const returningQueues = await queues.find({order: [login: request.params.login]});
  response.json(returningQueues);
```

But TypeScript error (56 missing properties(mostly internal Mongoose's) of type "User", which I store within an array) says that's I am wrong in my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have one condition on the array field, you can simply do:

```
queues.find({"order.login": request.params.login})
```

But if you have multiple conditions, you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
queues.find({
  order: { $elemMatch: { login: request.params.login, name: request.params.name } } 
})
```